# Externalize your maven project configuration where a class mostly consists of an AWS lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, configuration, amazon-dynamodb

I have a maven project, where each class is mostly one AWS lambda function.

It contains certain configuration values, which is for now stored & read from dynamo db.
But seems table cost is increasing (storage+reading), is there a better way/architecture to externalize your configs(no redeployment on modification of values) & not reading from DB.